# FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() returns JSON object instead of token string

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Sometimes when I call `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`, it returns the correct String token, but other times it returns a JSON string with a `token`, `appVersion`, and `timestamp` inside it's structure.

Anyone is having the same problem?

Comment: I'd file a bug against Firebase. The link is somewhere on their pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you are getting a JSON object is because the version you're probably using doesn't understand the new token format, so it just returns the whole JSON blob without pulling out the actual token. There are two things that you can do to resolve this issue:

1. Start using a more recent version (Firebase 9.6.0+) again and resolve all the issue you encountered.
2. As a workaround, if you see the JSON blob on your server, you can pull the actual token out manually. It will be under the `token` key.

Comment: I just wanted to post that after feedback from Firebase as well. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION FOR IONIC 3

```
 this.FCM.getToken().then((token) => {
        let mapedToken;
      try{
            mapedToken=JSON.parse(token).token;
          }
       catch{
             mapedToken=token;
         }
        //SAVING TOKEN 
        this.save(mapedToken);//function to save token

    });
```